# Can I search an entity's child properties in Symfony/ORM?

Tags: symfony, search, doctrine-orm

I'm creating a search function for my Company entity and putting my logic in a custom entity repository using Symfony 2 and Doctrine ORM.

The Company entity has a child collection Locations, as comapnies can have multiple locations, and a Company Name field.

I'm wondering if it's possible to search by Company Name and Location[1].address, Location[2].address, etc. using the Query Builder.

This is what I have so far and can't find a good resource for learning this.

```
*/ AppBundle/Repository/CompanyRepository.php */

class CompanyRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function findBySearch($options)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            $query->where('c.' . $key . ' LIKE :' . $key);
            $query->setParameter($key, '%' . $value . '%');
        }

        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

It looks like this doesn't work:

```
 $query->where('c.locations.city LIKE $city);
```

An example for the $options argument in findBySearch() would be:

```
[ 
    'companyName' => 'Mikes Company',
    'locations.city' => 'New York',
    'locations.state' => 'New York'
]
```

Any advice or links to resources are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You selected `c`, after that you want to find company with some location, it mean that in company entity you should have (with type Location)field `location`. Location entity shoud have field (string)city. Field location in Company entity should have oneToMany [association](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) with LocationEntity. After that when you will add company's name you also will add company's location. And now you can write:

```
$query->leftJoin('c.locations', 'locations');
$query->where('locations.city LIKE :city');
$query->setParameter('city', '%'.$city.'%')
```

If you want to use `c.locations.city` property of location object you should call there association. Like `leftJoin, innerJoin`. But I think `innerJoin` here will be more better and take just two line.

```
$query->innerJoin('c.locations', 'locations', 'WITH', 'locations.city LIKE (:city)')
$query->setParameter('city', '%'.$city.'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing `$query->where`  to `$query->andWhere`

`->andWhere()` can be used directly, without any ->where() before